# mysql query join doesnt work but sql "where" does

Tags: mysql, sql, join

i am trying to run a join query on mysql i am using following query:

```
SELECT `Reservation`.`id`
FROM `reservations` AS `Reservation` 
LEFT JOIN rates ON Reservation.postal_code=rates.postal_code
```

this gives my results only for "Reservation" table, and no results for the "rates" table at all, but the following query works fine

```
SELECT `Reservation`.`id`, rates.id 
FROM `reservations` AS `Reservation`, rates 
WHERE Reservation.postal_code = rates.postal_code
```

i am unsure what am i doing wrong, can someone please help?

**edit**

I was using cakephp and this is just a modified version of a query generated by cakephp and it didnt specify the fields in "select" case so i thought it isn't needed.

Comment: Define "the following query works fine". What is the data? What is the expected output?

Comment: Will provide interesting reading: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: +1 @StuperUser Great post, have never seen it.

Comment: @Adrian, the second query obviously means that it is selecting correct data from both tables

Answer (score 4):

You have to include them in the `SELECT`

```
SELECT `Reservation`.`id`, rates.* 
FROM `reservations` AS `Reservation` 
LEFT JOIN rates ON Reservation.postal_code=rates.postal_code
```

In your second query you have rates.id, that is including it.

**NOTE:** Don't use the kind of join from the second query you showed us. That's a cross join (theta join) and will make your query go really slow. Always use JOINS.

Comment: you are right, i was using the query generated by cakePHP and it didnt include the table name, i am myself very weak in mysql joins, thanks anyway

Comment: It's really simple. I edited my answer, take a look at the note. Get some simple MySQL/SQL book and will tell you how joins work, you'll have no problem with them. It's a piece of cake ;)

Comment: The second query is *not* a cross-join.  It is a regular INNER equi-join (in this case, a natural join) using an older SQL syntax.  It differs from the first query not only in the column list but in being INNER rather than LEFT OUTER, but if INNER is the desired logic then the second query is correct and valid syntax.

Comment: Actually, a theorical CROSS JOIN is a cartesian product, that is what he is doing. In MySQL, a "CROSS JOIN" (using that keyword)  "is a syntactic equivalent to INNER JOIN (they can replace each other)" (doc: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)

Comment: No, that is not a cartesian product.  It is an INNER JOIN.  In all versions of SQL.  There are table names and a JOIN predicate supplied.  The absence of the word JOIN does not turn the query into a cartesian product.  For it to be a cartesian product you would have to remove the `WHERE Reservation.postal_code = rates.postal_code`.

Answer (score 0):

The first query returns only a single column, `id`, from reservations.  Are you expecting to see data from rates as well?  You must mention those columns after the keyword `SELECT`.

The second query includes the column `id` from rates.

If you modify the queries so they return the same list of columns they will produce similar (but not identical results).  They will still differ in that the second query may return fewer rows — it will not include reservations with 0 corresponding rates (because it uses an INNER JOIN).

Comment: how do you specify which fields to select in cakephp? i am using this framework and it doesnt offer anyway to specify fields to select and neither it is selecting it itself

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with CakePHP (but this sort of thing is the reason why I always prefer to write my own SQL).

Answer (score 0):

The first query isn't selecting from the Rates table. Try this:

```
SELECT `Reservation`.`id`, `rates`.`id` 
FROM `reservations` AS `Reservation` 
LEFT JOIN rates ON Reservation.postal_code=rates.postal_code
```